# Different front page for anonymous users and authenticated users

Tags: javascript

I have an app in Drupalgap. I would like to display a different frontpage for anonymous users and authenticated users, for example /dashboard for the first and /user_listing for the last.

I have read "[Display Different Text for Anonymous and Authenticated Users](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Views/Displaying_a_View/Views_Render_Array/Other_Views_Render_Array_Examples/Display_Different_Text_for_Anonymous_and_Authenticated_Users)", but it is not the same scenario. (`/user_listing` has `['access user profiles']` as `access_arguments`.)

I also have tried with `drupalgap_goto()` without succeed.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [Context Reaction: Front page](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_reaction_site_frontpage) module, which extends the great [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module.

Create a new context and:

1. Add a condition for *User role*
2. Add a reaction *Front page* putting the path for the roles you want to affect.

Save the context and all should be done.

Comment: Sorry but I was talking about DrupalGap, not drupal core

Comment: Well, no experience there, sorry. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same page for both, and then render different things depending on if they are logged in or not:

```
function my_front_page_callback() {
  var content = {};
  if (!Drupal.user.uid) {
    content.foo = {
      markup: '<p>You are NOT logged in...</p>'
    };
  }
  else {
    content.bar = {
      markup: '<p>You are logged in...</p>'
    };
  }
  return content;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

drupalgap_goto() worked for me.

I have front page set to go to qleva_start which has this page callback:

```
function qleva_start_page() {
  try {
    if (drupalgap_user_has_role('authenticated user')) {
      drupalgap_goto('qleva_start_auth');
    }
    else {
      drupalgap_goto('user/login');
    }
  }
  catch (error) { console.log('qleva_start - ' + error); }
}
```

so if anon, front is login page and if authenticated, it is qleva_start_auth